# Как обратиться к КОНКРЕТНОМУ Селекту?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сгенерироавные формы, в них есть кнопки и селекты... На кнопке висит событие добавить данные в lokalStorage.

Все хорошо все работает, кнопка не сработает пока не выберется нужное значение селекта..... Но ни как не могу обратиться к КОНКРЕТНОМУ СЕЛЕКТУ из десятка....
Помогите пожалуйста...

```
function addToCart1() {
//Добавляем товар в корзтну 
// ----------------------------- МОЯ ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ ---------------------
var CanopySize = $('.CanopySize').val(); 
// ----------------------- Так я обращаюсь к первому селекту на всей странице
if( $('.CanopySize').val() == '--Выберите размер--') {
  alert ('Выберите размер парашюта');
} else {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  cart[id] = 1;
  localStorage.setItem('CanopySize', CanopySize);
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  alert('Основной парашют добавлен. Выберите ранец.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в функцию передавать номер Селекта. И внутри функции делать что-то вроде

```
function addToCart1(number) {
var CanopySize = $('.CanopySize')[number]; 
if( CanopySize.val() == '--Выберите размер--') {
  alert ('Выберите размер парашюта');
} else {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  cart[id] = 1;
  localStorage.setItem('CanopySize', CanopySize.val());
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  alert('Основной парашют добавлен. Выберите ранец.');
}
```